# Objects Not Found when trying to set DataLastRow

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the With ws in my macro.  When trying to find the last row of data, I was using: `.Range("F4:F" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`.  And it worked.

I thought about breaking the calculation of the last row into its own line: `DataLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

But now it's saying Object not Found - ***DataLastRow =*** ..  Why is that?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DataLastRow As Long

With ws

    Set DataLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Update $ - % Chg Formula
    .Range("F4").Formula = "=(E4/(E4-G4))-1"
    .Range("F4").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    .Range("F4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F4:F" & DataLastRow)
```

Comment: Since DataLastRow is a Long, you don't need the Set statement.  Also, ws has never been set to something.

Comment: Oh ok.. so if I was to `Dim DataLastRow as Range`, would I need the Set Statement?

Comment: Yes, if the right side evaluated to a Range.